# Web app deployed on kestrel goes into idle mode

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, kestrel

I have  ASP .Net core webapi deployed on IIS 7.5 (Windows 2008 R2). I have controllers as well as listener classes (which wait for a message to arrive on a RabbitMQ message) which perform the same functionality.

The problem is whenever webapi is deployed on IIS or has some idle time, the RabbitMQ messages don't get picked up. Only if I make a API call to the control does the application 'wake up' and picks up the message.

Tweaks I have tried:
In the application pool,

1. set 'Idle timeout' to 0 .
2. set the 'Disable Overlapped Recycled' to true.
3. set 'Disable recycling for configuration changes'.

I have no idea what is causing this. I need the application to pick up messages immediately and have no idle time. Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you the code part on how and when you are listening on RabbitMQ messages. Also do you see w3wp.exe process running always in the IIS server?

Comment: Have you find any alternative solution without send unnecessary messages